# Shorten a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression, that filter numbers from a string without any dot in it. How can I shorten my expression?

```
myString.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' ).replace(/\./g, '')
```

Comment: `myString.replace( /\D/g, '' )`

Comment: What do you mean by "filter numbers from a string without any dot in it?" Can you provide some sample input and output? Do you just want to remove anything that isn't `0-9`?

Comment: @Merott: Inside a character class, a `.` is always treated as a literal `.`, no need escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' )`, you remove any character that is not a digit or a literal dot.

With `.replace(/\./g, '')`, you remove all dots.

To combine, just use

```
myString = myString.replace( /\D/g, '' )
```

The `/\D/g` will match all characters that are not digits.